# Possible to remove mimetype information in ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, formatting, actionmailer

My apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find a similar question.

I tested `ActionMailer` on my app, and thankfully, I was able to send email. However, I noticed, that in the 2 messages I sent, the following was added at the top and bottom of every message

```
----==_mimepart_54a2dba13bc69_1545c33b51ac154d3
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

I would like my emails to look a little more professional, so is it possible to remove that part from your emails?

Also, the same message is rendered twice in the email, once in HTML and  once in Text Format.

Edit: I use `Gmail` to check emails, and that was what I saw in the message body.

Comment: Can you post your mailer code and the mail template?

Comment: What is a mail template? I know mailers have models and views, but I haven't heard of templates

Comment: Check out your app/mailers folder. Is anything there?